# Appending parent element along with its child tags to new etree using lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, elementtree

Just a quick question. Sorry if it is basic, i tried googling but didn't get anything useful. Here is my query. i have 2 LXML etree, PFB
XML-1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
   <child c="1">
      <e1>abc</e1>
      <e2>abc</e2>
      <e3>abc</e3>
      <e4>
         <e41>xyz</e41>
         <e41>zyx</e41>
      </e4>
   </child>
   <child c="2">
      <e1>abc</e1>
      <e2>abc</e2>
      <e3>abc</e3>
      <e4>
         <e41>xyz</e41>
         <e41>zyx</e41>
      </e4>
   </child>
</parent>
```

XML-2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child c="3">
      <e1>abc</e1>
      <e2>abc</e2>
      <e3>abc</e3>
      <e4>
         <e41>xyz</e41>
         <e41>zyx</e41>
      </e4>
    </child>
</parent>
```

FINAL RESULT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child c="3">
      <e1>abc</e1>
      <e2>abc</e2>
      <e3>abc</e3>
      <e4>
         <e41>xyz</e41>
         <e41>zyx</e41>
      </e4>
    </child>
    <child c="1">
      <e1>abc</e1>
      <e2>abc</e2>
      <e3>abc</e3>
      <e4>
         <e41>xyz</e41>
         <e41>zyx</e41>
      </e4>
   </child>
</parent>
```

Now i want to append XML-2 with "child c='1'" element along with its child elements from XML-1. Right i am looping through its child and appending XML-2. Is there any way to append XML-2 without looping. i mean at one go. Thanks in advance. Don't ask me what i tried. My current code(looping through elements) works fine. And i am not sure even if it is possible.

Comment: post the final result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just added how the final result should look like.

Comment: *(looping through elements* - no need to loop, just `find` method

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, Just found about deepcopy.

If you want to copy an element to a different position in lxml.etree, consider creating an independent deep copy using the copy module from Python's standard library:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy

>>> element = etree.Element("neu")
>>> element.append( deepcopy(root[1]) )
```